# how to change the spliting factor of args to "," and not " " discord.py

Tags: python, split, discord, discord.py

I want the splitting factor of args to be "," and not " ", like i want "1, 3, 5" to split like "1", "3", "5" and not "1," "3," "5,".

code:
`th ,pp, *_ = args`

or just help me split the args. i've tried it , here's the code i tried:

```
t, *_ = args
tl = t.split(2, [",", ", "])
th = [item[0] for item in tl]
pp = [item[1] for item in tl]
```

Comment: what is ```args```?

Comment: What's the type of `t` and `tl`?

Answer (score 0):

Just send your delimiter to `.split()` function:

```
mylist = "1, 3, 5".split(', ')

Expected output:
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

`t.split(2, [",", ", "])` is invalid. The arguments of `split` are `sep=None, maxsplit=-1`.

If you want to use several/variable separators you need to use a regex:

```
import re

t = '1,2, 3'
re.split(r',\s*', t)
```

Output: `['1', '2', '3']`